# Writing file with NSFileManager in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io, nsdata, nsfilemanager

(I'm not native English speaker. Sorry about my bad English...)

I succeed to write file before with this code.

```
// worked code...

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"myfile.txt"];

NSString *myStr = @"this is a string";

if( ! [myStr writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] )
  return FALSE;
else
  return TRUE;
```

And now I want to change this code with `NSFileManager`.
So, I tried just like this.

```
// not worked code...

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"myfile.txt"];

NSString *myStr = @"this is a string";
NSData *fileData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSFileManager *fm;

if( [fm createFileAtPath: filePath contents: fileData attributes: nil] == NO )
  return FALSE;
else
  return TRUE;
```

Everytime when I build this code, it keeps returned as false...
Am I doing something wrong?? Please help me

Comment: can you please log the `filePath` value? usually it is a bad practice to use `– stringByAppendingString:` for adding a _path component_ to the current URL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here is my path. `/Users/[myUserName]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/08F89652-CA57-4136-9889-46458D00AC9A/Documentsmyfile.txt` And after using `stringByAppendingString`, it changed as `Documents/myfile.txt`. But, even I checked if the file exist, it still failed to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is basically the `NSFileManager` method won't overwrite an existing file where as the `NSString` method *will*:

From the `NSFileManager` [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:):

> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the operation was successful or if the item already exists, otherwise `NO`.

From the `NSString` [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:):

> **Discussion**
>
> This method overwrites any existing file at path.

If you always want to write a fresh copy of the data, then check if the file exists first and delete it if it does.

**ALSO**: You should not be using `[NSString stringByAppendingString:]` to construct the filepath; instead use `[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]`; I expect you aren't even writing the file you think you are, because of this.

Better still, use `NSURL` to refer to files; which is the preferred method.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As you said, I used `[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]`. and the log of `filePath` looks good. I checked if the file exists(`[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath`). And if it does, I deleted it(`[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath]`). But, even there is no file, it failed to write...

Comment: Don't mind what I said. It worked. I forgot to write `NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];`

Answer (score 1):

Your NSFileManager is not set to any file manager.

Instead you should try to initialise it with the defaultManager with the following code.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

Comment: ...why I forgot this? sorry